# Rails find all order, found 0 results expected 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble sorting my table based on the votes column, votes is a multivalued attribute so I use count and try to sort it based on that. here is the code

```
@topics = Topic.find(:all,:order=>'@topic.votes.count DESC')
```

Rails returns an error that says

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TopicsController#index
Couldn't find all Topics with 'id': (all, {:order=>"@topic.votes.count DESC"}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

Just starting out with rails and still confused with some things, your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ahmed and snehal, I was able to find out the answer I'm looking for, which is

```
Topic.left_outer_joins(:votes).group('topics.id').order('count(topics.id) DESC')
```

Answer (score 1):

this is Rails 2 syntax being used in higher Rails version.

You can do something like this:

```
Topic.joins(:votes).group('topics.id').order('count(topics.id) DESC')
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that the syntax was already outdated.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of join include is best and faster option

```
Topic.include(:votes).group('topics.id').order('count(topics.id) DESC')
```